# Modularizing a login page

Tags: php, authentication, global-variables, modularity

Currently, we have a page called `login.php` and whenever we determine that the user may need authorization for something, we include it:

```
if($userLevelNotHighEnough) {
    require "login.php";
}
```

This page checks that the user is logged in, but if not, it generates a login page and exits. There are a lot of optional things that the login page does (like printing certain messages, allowing certain special logins, etc.) which are messy business logic things. These options are currently handled by setting variables in the calling script, which are accessed by login.php, i.e.:

```
// in calling script
if($userLevelNotHighEnough) {
    $someOptionalParameter = "my value";
    require "login.php";
}

/** ============================ **/

// in login.php
if(!empty($someOptionalParameter)) {
    // do something
}
```

As you might imagine, this sort of code is prevalent throughout the codebase, and it makes adding to the codebase *very* difficult, especially for those who are relatively new to the code.

What alternatives are there to this sort of structure?

My initial idea was that we could make a function called `checkLogin` instead and pass it an associative array of optional parameters, but this doesn't seem *that* much better than the current system.

Comment: Well a full MVC arcitecture with access control defined at the routing level would be much simpler to maintain, but would essentially require a full rewrite of the current application

Comment: I agree with Steve. Use a well-established framework like CodeIgniter or Zend or any of the hundreds of others out there. It will make development a lot smoother, more robust, consistent, and simple.

Comment: @crunch That would potentially help, but unfortunately not really my decision to make. The people I'm working with like the control that comes with hand-rolling (and I agree with that desire to an extent), so I'm looking to restructure rather than use a third-party framework. -- Steve, what did you mean "with access control defined at the routing level"?

Comment: Well with an MVC architecture, you have a single entry point (typically index.php) that all requests go through. This file will carry out some bootstrapping (load classes, load config, connect to db etc) then pass control to a router component that determines what controller and method to load. This centralization means you can define simple rules here, such as `if request matches /admin/* then run auth check`. Maintenance is simple because all the rules are in one place

Comment: And dont think that MVC automatically means a rigid full stack framework, building your own router is simple, or use a microframework like slim or fatfreephp (my go to tool) that allows you to use as much or as little framework code as you need.